# jquerylightbox does not work - is it issue with the script file include sequence?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to use jQuery.Lighbox library but it fails to find the lightBox method.

What I did:

include jquery.lightbox.js (immediatly after jquery itself):

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link href="/Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link href="/Content/jquery.lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.5.3.js"></script>
        <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
        <script src="/Scripts/jquery.lightbox.js"></script>

  ...
 <head>
```

and within the body I am am wiring up the lightbox code to html elements:

```
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        try
        {
            $('#gallery a').lightBox(); // Select all links with lightbox class
        }
        catch (err) {
            var txt = "";
            txt = "There was an error on this page.\n\n";
            txt += "Error description: " + err.message + "\n\n";
            txt += "Click OK to continue.\n\n";
            alert(txt);
        }
    });
    </script>
```

and quite expectantly the js code throws an error:

> There was an error on this page.Error description: Object [object
>   Object] **has no method 'lightBox'Click OK to continue.**

I am new to jQuery, so if you can give me a hint what did I do wrong and how to fix it.

Thank you.

**edit:**

resolved : it turned out jquery.js has been include twice, and it was hiding jquery.lightbox function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Object [object Object] has no method 'lightBox'

this mean lightBox method is not found which means lightbox js is not loaded properly..check it out...view the source..and make sure your path is correct

Comment: thanks. is there a way in javascript to print a paths of all included script files? i am quite sure the path is correct ... need to check if other jQuery functions available though.

Comment: jQuery functions seems to be working fine, it is only a jq.lightbox funciton is not available... even though locally both jq.js and jq.lightbox.js is in the same folder and the include code is not different too. weird...

Comment: one way to check for loaded file is...if using chrome or firefox >  right click on the browser window >  cilck on view page source > and click the lightboxjs link > if it opens it mean it is loaded.. :)